# Sequelize hasMany with "Where"

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-5, sequelize.js

I am coming from Laravel where you can work with Eloquent. In Eloquent you can do something like:

```
$this->hasOne('App\Models\Member', 'family_id')->where('relation', '=', 1);
```

In order to get a specific member within a wider scope.

Is the same thing possible to do in Sequelize? I see I can do

```
Family.hasMany(models.Member);
```

or

```
Family.hasOne(models.Member);
```

but I don't see where I Can add a constraint. Any ideas?

Comment: The `hasMany` and `hasOne` examples you gave are to set up Associations between tables. Are you trying to do a search query? If so, you can use `Family.findOne({})` or `Family.findAll({})` search query, and inside these queries you can add a `where` constraint. See more here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Comment: I was trying to create a relationship that took a type into account so that I would not have to search through each "member" every time I was looking for a specific one. I wanted to create a "mainMember" which would automatically return a member with a constraint in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to accomplish this. The where clause is moved to the controller and not predefined in the model. It would be done like this:

```js
models.Family.findAll({
    include:[
        {
            model : models.Member,
            where: { relation : 1 }
        },
    ]
})
```